# How to download current screen as PDF and Image using html2canvas JS?

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I want to download the current screen as a PDF/Image using html2canvas.js.

1) Download current Screen as image
The following code is working fine for me.

HTML

```
<head>
  <script src="html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <button onclick="download()" class="btn btn-danger">Download</button>
</body>
```

JS

```
function download(){
  html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
      a.download = $.now()+'.jpg';
      a.click();
    }
  });
}
```

2) Download current screen as PDF
How to implement this using html2canvas.js? How can I download and save the current screen as PDF?

Kindly help. Thank you!

Comment: have you tried `application/pdf` MIME type??

Comment: @RishiVishwakarma I tried this but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen that `html2canvas` wont work with `pdf` download.
But tehre is a tool called **[JsPDF](http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.debug.js)**

try this -

## HTML Code

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas> 
<button id="download">Download Pdf</button>
```

## JS code

```
html2canvas($("#canvas"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {         
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
            'image/png');              
        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
        doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
    }
});
```

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/p4s5k59s/490/

Comment: but this won't handle more than one page.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately html2canvas.js doesn't support pdf. You can use [JsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/examples/images.html) to create a pdf out of the generated image.

Comment: thank you for the information. It helped me to move ahead in my code